# Why is my UWP manipulation stopping early?

Tags: c#, uwp, touch

I am writing an control that allows you to to drag around elements on the subcontrol. I'm doing this by creating an ItemsControl and binding the Manipulation events to reorder elements (like you can with the listview, but visually very different). However, when I actually alter the order of the children on the root panel, the manipulationCompleted event fires, and there are no further manipulationDelta events (even though the pointer or finger is still down and moving).

XAML snipppet:

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="TopGrid"                  
              ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY"
              ManipulationStarted="TopGrid_ManipulationStarted"
              ManipulationDelta="TopGrid_ManipulationDelta"
              ManipulationCompleted="TopGrid_ManipulationCompleted">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

And the C# that seems to cause manipulation to end. This is within the ManipulationDelta event handler:

```
List<UIElement> children = new List<UIElement>();
children.AddRange(wp.Children.Where(u => (u as ContentPresenter)?.Content != _dragObject).Take(current));
children.Add(wp.Children.First(u => (u as ContentPresenter)?.Content == _dragObject));
children.AddRange(wp.Children.Where(u => (u as ContentPresenter)?.Content != _dragObject).Skip(current));
ItemsPanelRoot.Children.Clear();
children.ForEach(u => ItemsPanelRoot.Children.Add(u));
```

Comment: why the children are cleared in ManipulationDelta event handler? seems to me this should be done in the completed event handler.

Comment: The children are cleared and readded in a different order so that you see them reordering as you manipulate them individually.

Comment: is the completed event fired when they are cleared and readded?

Comment: Actually, it turns out the parent UserControl just stops firing ManipulationDelta events when the children are cleared and readded. The ManipulationCompleted event only fires after you lift your finger and _re-tap_ the control.